# Constructor with "this" in C++?

Tags: c++

In Java, we can write as following:

```
public class Demo{
    private int val;
    public Demo(int val){this.val = val;}
    public Demo(){this(0);}
}
```

However, it does not work in C++:

```
class Demo{
    private:
       int _val;
    public:
       Demo(int val):_val(val){}
       Demo(){this(0);}
}
```

How to revise this code?

Answer (score 8):

With C++11, you could use delegate constructor:

```
Demo():Demo(0){ }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this just creates a temporary `Demo`.

Comment: I'll blame it on being tired, but `: Demo(0)`

Comment: @chris Demo:Demo(0){} ?

Comment: @chris yes and I am a bit drunk as well after beer+ bbq

Answer (score 4):

```
class Demo{
    private:
       int _val;
    public:
       Demo(int val):_val(val){}
       Demo() :_val(0) {}
}
```

Or

```
class Demo{
    private:
       int _val;
    public:
       Demo(int val):_val(val){}
       Demo() :Demo(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Added the delegation way. I don't really see the point in this example though.

Answer (score 1):

Or this approach which is useful when there are a lot of members to initialise (and before C++11):

```
class Demo{
    private:
       int _val;
       void Init( int val )
       {
           _val = val;
       }
    public:
       Demo(int val){Init(val);}
       Demo(){Init(0);}
}
```